# The best way to redirect all views to/from one view (e.g UnderConstructionView)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to somehow route all views to one particular view? I would like to have an "Under Construction view" that is always the default view until i "flip a switch" without having to build. Until then all other controller action routes to this view.

I would love to know if i can do it in web.config or if i have to have some if/else in RegisterRoutes in Global.asax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can write a custom filter attribute that reads a flag from web.config and redirect requests to under construction page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class UnderConstAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly static AppSettingsReader _reader;
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
              _reader = new AppSettingsReader();
              if(_reader.GetValue("UnderConst", typeof(bool)))
                 filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Underconst.html");
        }
    }
}
```

and you have to add key to web.config file

```
<appSettings><add key="UnderConst" value="false"/></appSettings>
```

and you have to add this filter to global action filter collection in global.asax file

Comment: Just an update. To make your code work I had to remove the readonly and but a (bool) cast at the beginning of the if statement like so  if ((bool)_reader.GetValue("UnderConst",typeof(bool))).

Comment: How did you manage to redirect to a view? Because in the example, it redirect to an html page (that works) but if you redirect to a view (for example "/Home/ComingSoon/", it enter in an endless redirect process... How to avoid that? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: remove filter attribute for commingsoon action

Answer (score 7):

Place a file called `app_offline.htm` into the root of your directory and this will be displayed for all requests.

Once you remove (or rename) this file your web requests will be processed as usual again.

Comment: Thanx, I could do that but then i can´t use my "ultra dynamic Under Construction view" where i collect emails,etc. and interact with the user. Because ASP.NET checks for the presence of this file and, if it exists, stops the app-domain so the application cannot run. I would like to avoid that.