# Display a custom html page when publishing to IIS in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment, app-offline.htm

I have an MVC5 application and I want to display an html (or htm) page while publishing the application to IIS server. So, I tried different methods by using app_offline.htm as indicated on [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying a Code Update](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-a-code-update). But none of them works properly in MVC. Is there a better approach to make this?

Comment: please explain it properly, do you want to use routconfig for default page?

Comment: I do not know it sorry, I just want to display a custom page i.e. "Under Construction" page when I publish the application to IIS sever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129633/the-best-way-to-redirect-all-views-to-from-one-view-e-g-underconstructionview

Comment: @Zaki Thanks, I had look at that page before creating this issue. But I am looking a better approach with a smart integration to the project. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like app_offline.html customization not supported yet. See https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/530.
Also, there is similar question [Custom app_offline.htm file during publish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846097/1193727).